# Installing a Package that asks debconf questions doesn't work with the Software-Center

Tags: 14.04, software-center, package-management, debconf

I am building an automatic configure Package for our environment and it has to ask a few debconf questions when installing. Until Ubuntu 13.10 it was no problem installing it via the GUI but since 14.04 the Software-Center just hangs when installing.

After installing libgtk2-perl separately this is no longer a problem and the questions are getting asked.

Is this a Bug in the Software-Center or how am I supposed to handle it?

My current workaround is a Pre-Depends on libgtk2-perl but this shouldn't be the final solution and sucks for people installing it via Terminal.

Comment: looks like your app depends upon `libgtk2-perl`. Doesn't look like a serious concern, is it?

Comment: My program doesn't need it, but the debconf frontend used by the Software-Center needs it, my package just needs debconf.

Comment: You solved my problem! I couldn't find anything about this. My package works in Ubuntu before 14.04 and suddenly started freezing in 14.04. The only difference for me is that even a `Pre-Depends` didn't work (or a manual `apt-get install` in `preinst` for that matter). I had to run `apt-get install libgtk2-perl` *before* installing my package. I'll probably submit a bug report tomorrow, but a fix for now would be really nice... sigh...